# Best method to store alt tags in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am currently building a blog with Django and I would like to add a alt tag to my images for improving my SEO.

My model is like this at the moment. My images are inside the Post class in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
```

My first thought is to define a separate Image class with the tag as one of its properties:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    alt_tag = models.Charfield()

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
```

So is this a correct or the prefered way of handling alt tags? I am using Amazon S3 to store these images, so maybe I could store alt tag as metadata. Or use a third party package like [django-alttext](https://pypi.org/project/django-alttext/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is this a correct or the prefered way of handling alt tags?

I would say this a fine design choice. As this makes it clear the alt data is part of the image, and not of the Post. This allows also to reuse previous Image objects within a new Post.

You could also think about making the relation between the Image and Post a ManyToMany, as this would allow posts without an image, but also with multiple images.

---

> I am using Amazon S3 to store these images, so maybe I could store alt tag as metadata.

I don't know what these metadata thing is on S3, but if it configurable and as easy for you to maintain, you could look at this option. But I would prefer to keep it within the Django model. As maintaining the data can be done at one place.

---

> Or use a third party package like django-alttext?

Don't know the app, but it's always possible to use third party. But you have to make sure the project is regularly maintained. What are the dependencies? How much issues are there open on their community site. Would it bloat your project, like would it do 1000x more than what you need. Decide based on these question if you want the 3rd party software or DIY.

Comment: "As this makes it clear the alt data is part of the image, and not of the Post." Which can also be the wrong choice. A generic image of a line graph in decline can be used "Stock market collapses", "Crime rate drops", you name it. "Line graph with declining value", would aid finding the image for the authors, but not improve your SEO.

Comment: Good point, haven't thoughed about it that way. Another option as a design choice could be Post and Image objects, both without an alt field. And a M2M between the two, but with a through model. PostImage, with FKs to Post and Image and an alt CharField.

Comment: Thank you for your points, it really helped to clear my mind. I was not considering if this third party package will bring problems in the future if not well maintained